# O que fazer para diminuir o processamento da Memoria RAM no VBA?

Tags: vba, memória, macro

Estou fazendo uma planilha, e sempre que rodo minhas macros ele começa a travar, eu vi o quanto de Ram ta usando e ta 1.6GB e o arquivo cada vez que salva ele aumenta de tamanho significativamente, agora esta com 350mb. Só que nessa planilha eu não adiciono novos dados, eu substituio os antigos apenas.

Comment: Tem como colocar o código que você utiliza? Provavelmente você está guardando muitos itens na memória

Comment: Existe alguns truques para reduzir a utilização de memória, como tirar a visualização, separar funções com muitas linhas, segregar o código para utilizar classes, porém teria de ver o código para dar alguma dica. Se puder poste o código que está gerando essa grande quantidade de utilização de memória que com certeza alguém poderá ajudar.